# JPA, Combine @JoinColumn and @Column

Tags: java, jpa

Is it possible to use both @JoinColumn and @Column for the same field in JPA, enabling updates from both?

Lets say I have an entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Assuming the Address object already exists - when creating this object, I need to fetch the address from the database before persisting a Person. This is my current design throughout my application, but it can cause performance issues. Is it possible to add the possibility to persist by use of ID only, while keeping possibility to persist with the real object (for not having to change huge amounts of code elsewhere)? Something like this

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Address address;

    @Column(name="address_id")
    private Integer addressId;

    // getters and setters
}

em.persist(new Person(1));
em.persist(new Person(getAddress(1)));
```

Is it possible to annotate to allow for both these persist lines? MY current belief is that one of the fields need to have `insertable = false`

Comment: I do not realy understand your quetion. Column and JoinColumn are both only annotations to define database column names and attributes, no relation is defined by this. My First question would be, is this it possible that an address is used by more then one person? or has one person one address and if two people live at the same address the address get redudant? Any way, you should use OneToMany or OneToOne annotation to define the relation between your person and your address and when you define the cascading to only refresh, a persist or merge on the person would never create a address, too.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the ManyToOne-annotation

Comment: your last assumption is right, one of the fields must have `insertable = false`, (and also `updatable = false` and `deletable = false`) so that field would be just a read-only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such duplicate mapping is not possible, because it could lead to conflicts. What if you set the `address` field to an Address with ID = X, and then `addressId` to another ID = Y? Which one should JPA take into account on save? That's why you have to specify it and make one of those fields `insertable=false, updatable=false`.

A solution to your problem is `EntityManager.getReference()` method. It returns a "proxy" object for given class and ID without actually loading it from DB. This way you can set the `address` reference in `Person` object and persist it:

```
em.persist(new Person(em.getReference(Address.class, 1)));
```

Thanks to this solution you don't need the `addressId` field at all.